# trigger jquery datepicker via a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a long list of items with date fields.  Allowing jQuery to assign the datepicker to all the items with the class of datepicker is creating a pop up script (*something to the effect of the script is runnning a really long time, do you want to stop the script, yes or no*) not to mention it is taking a while for the document be rendered.  When we remove the datepicker class, the page is rendered almost immediately.  So, what I'd like to do is have the input field where the date would normally be populated with a trigger (link or graphic) that can be clicked to fire the datepicker popup calendar.  This way, we only need to provide the popup calendar only on the field that actually needs it.

**IDs are not available, only the name attribute is.**

```
    <tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='StartDate' /> <span onclick='ShowCalendar()'>Calendar</span></td>
    <td>other fields</td>
    <td>more fields</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: The "LOOK" and functionality of this link is what I have in mind but the way it is implemented wont work since the list is so long. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/icon-trigger.html

Comment: Any other thoughts on this problem?  My topic has kind of stalled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createDatepicker(input) {
        $(input).datepicker().datepicker("show");
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="someText" /><br />
<input type="text" name="someDate" onclick="createDatepicker(this)" /><br />
<input type="text" name="someText" /><br />
<input type="text" name="someDate" onclick="createDatepicker(this)" /><br />
```

Using this answer, I constructed the above solution:
[How to run date picker on the first onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859453/how-to-run-date-picker-on-the-first-onclick-event)

Comment: Your "loop" isn't  in a table tag and IE is notoriously slow at rendering tables.  A few hundred would probably be okay but we are talking close to 10k rows.

Comment: You can try another selector type:
$( "[name$=Date]" ).datepicker();

Comment: I've been told we  cannot use selectors, we have to use functions.  :(

Comment: What about this version, it could be what you are looking for.

Comment: @ondej-xicht-svtlik thanks for that link, it wasn't perfect but close enough!

Comment: I'm glad I could have helped. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is pass the current element to your ShowCalendar function using the "this" keyword. You can then use that as a reference to find the corresponding date field by traversing the dom using jQuery functions. In your example, you could use the prev() function.

```
<tr>
<td><input type='text' name='StartDate' /> <span  onclick='ShowCalendar(this)'>Calendar</span></td>
<td>other fields</td>
<td>more fields</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: how might the function look?  This is what I have so far but it isn't working.  by not working, I mean the calendar isn't appearing.
        `function ShowCalendar(el,nm,ordr){
 alert(el + ' ' + nm + ' ' + ordr); 
 // this,'proposedlivedate',#ordr#)
 $( "#" + nm ).datepicker();
        }`

Comment: try this function ShowCalendar(el,nm,ordr)
{ 
 var datefield = $(el).prev();
 datefield.datepicker(); 
}

Answer (score 0):

You needed to have your datepicker files loaded in the page. Then use something like this
In below code "todo_date" is a textfield id which is used to trigger the jquery datepicker.

```
$( "#todo_date" ).datepicker();
function myFunc(){
  $("#calendar_img").click(function(e) { 
     $("#todo_date").datepicker("show");
  });
}
```

Hope this helps